# Flex Builder not building new source code

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I have imported an existing project into flex but any changes I make to the source are not being built and displayed when I test run the application. The original files which are in the bin-debug folder dont seem to be changing at all.

I have tried cleaning the project, deleting the bin-debug folder even reinstalling flex builder, but nothing has solved the problem.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290768/flex-builder-3-executing-old-source-codes) which was about the same problem but none of the advice helped.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you imported the project did you do a default import (copies everything into your workspace) or an "Existing Projects into Workspace" import?

If you did the default (listed as "FlexBuilder/Flex Project" under the import source) then you might be changing the wrong code.  If you're looking in the original project's location for the SWFs to run then you're in the wrong place, as the SWFs you build will be in the new location.

One quick way to test to see if your code is actually being compiled would be to intentionally put a compile error in there.  If the compiler chokes on it then your code *is* being compiled.

Comment: I've added some syntax errors to the code. It's immediately flagged by the editor but when I hit ctrl+f11 the page is displayed fine (though as the original file).

The import I did was other->general->existing projects into workspace (without the copy files option).

I have two computers and I followed the exact same steps. The new code is compiled fine in one, but still not in the other!

The mind boggles.

Comment: Well if you try to run it when a compile failed it will just run the last successfully compiled SWF.  But that's weird that it's not running it when it's new.  Maybe try manually deleting the compiled SWF and see what happens.  Maybe it's having trouble overwriting it.

Comment: That just loads the .html wrapper file, but there is no application in it! If i delete the .html wrapper file it comes up with a "file not found" error.

Comment: If it's saying file not found then the SWF isn't being compiled.  If you're not getting any compile errors then it should show up.  That's very strange.

Answer (score 1):

There's another thing you can try.  I just ran into a weird issue where FB was caching a compile error, and even after fixing the file it still showed the error.  Even after doing a clean, restarting FB, etc.

I found a place where FB caches information for the project, and for some reason it wasn't clearing things it should.  It's possible your project's cache got messed up and it's messing up the compile somehow.  You can try deleting it (might need to delete and re-import your project though).

The cache is at:
workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\

I just made a [blog post about this](http://blog.aherrman.com/2010/05/clear-improperly-cached-compile-errors.html), in case you'd find it useful.